# Use same shortcut for View.TfsPendingChanges and View.PendingChanges

Tags: visual-studio, version-control, keyboard-shortcuts

In Visual Studio, it seems you need to use `View.TfsPendingChanges` when working with a TFS project, and `View.PendingChanges` when working with a Git project. I would like to use the same shortcut key to see my pending changes, regardless of source control. Is there a clever way to make this happen?

Comment: I came here because I had exactly the same question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my dorky solution which requires use of an [AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com/) script.

I have `View.PendingChanges` mapped to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> and `View.TfsPendingChanges` mapped to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>. Since a project in TFS will ignore the `View.PendingChanges` and a project in Git will ignore the `View.TfsPendingChanges`, it doesn't hurt to send both shortcuts.

Having this script constantly running will quickly send both <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> inside Visual Studio.

```
#IfWinActive Visual Studio
  ^0::Send ^0^!0 ; Open Git Pending Changes and TFS Pending Changes
#IfWinActive
```

Though it would be better for Visual Studio to simply let View.PendingChanges work as expected for both Git and TFS projects...